# How can I train my 12 week old puppy to pee less frequently?

Tags: dogs, toilet-training

I have a 12 week old Doberman pup I take him out every 30 minutes we even set a timer. He goes everytime he's outside but he will still pee in the house. I don't let him wonder off alone either and he shows no signs like sniffing or circling. I have no clue what to do about this if I can't even tell he's gonna go. It's like he just wants to pee whenever he pleases. He is crated and will sleep through the whole night with absolutely no problem, not even a peep so I know it's not his bladder. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: 30 minutes is a bit to long at that age when they are active. Also do it after eating,  drinking,  napping, playing.

Comment: Did you ever get the Doberman trained? I have a 12 week old boxer and I am experiencing the same thing you went through.

Answer (score 4):

First, to set your expectations, 12 weeks is very young to be housetrained. You are going to need to be very vigilant for at least another month or two or three!

Next, when a puppy urinates, that doesn't mean his bladder is empty, especially with a male. Are you bringing him back inside immediately? Try staying outside for at least another 5 minutes to see if he will go again.

The gist of housetraining is to teach the dog that it is unacceptable to go inside, but that it is rewarding to go outside. You need to watch him constantly when he is inside and not confined to a crate. If he starts to go without warning, say "Ah-Ah-Ah No!" loudly, which may startle him to stop. Immediately carry him outside and see if he will finish. Give lavish praise and treats if he does outside.

Watch for signs that he might be thinking of going, and try to get him out before the accident starts. Most dogs have a pattern or rhythm that becomes predictable. It might help to keep a journal of when your dog goes to recognize this pattern over time.

Good luck, and I do commiserate with you. I have a 4 month-old Golden Retriever who is still not trustworthy, but has started to whine when she needs to go out. It is a LOT of work now, but it will pay off for many years to come if your dog is reliably housetrained.

Answer (score 0):

I read about these [tips](https://web.archive.org/web/20160725122204/http://www.howtoteachadog.com/how-to-potty-train-a-dog) about potty training and it worked for me and my labrador retriever. Try and establish a routine with your puppy and reward him when he does it right. You can also use word association which will give him the cue that it is time to go.